# How to add unbounded combobox into grid dynamically

Tags: axapta, x++

I would like to ask :

1. how I can add an unbounded combobox  in formBuildGridControl at runtime

   ```
   FormBuildStringControl  formString = formBuildGridControl.addDataField(form.dataSource(i).id(),DictField.id());

   formString.label(fieldId2Name(dictTable1.id(),fieldId));

   FormBuildComboBoxControl combo = formString.addControl(FormControlType::ComboBox,fieldId2Name(dictTable1.id(),f eldId));

   combo.label(fieldId2Name(dictTable1.id(),fieldId));
   ```

the problem is that when I am trying to assign the combobox label I get an exception that the combo is null.

Generally I would like to achive, to import dynamically an unbounded combobox with any datasource, but instand of datasource I would like to bounded with a enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, you are trying to add your combobox control to `formString`, for some reason. Shouldn't you add it to `formBuildGridControl`? I.e.

```
FormBuildComboBoxControl combo = formBuildGridControl.addControl(FormControlType::ComboBox, fieldId2Name(dictTable1.id(), fieldId));

combo.label(fieldId2Name(dictTable1.id(), fieldId));
```

Comment: my bad, that's correct , but still the grid control is empty.

Comment: The problem was that was not even one  bounded  datafield with the grid.So the combobox was there but i cannot see it because the grid had no lines at all. Works like a charm.